# missing return statement }

Tags: java

Помогите! Нужно получить минимальное число из трёх, но есть ошибка

```
public static int min(int a, int b, int c) {

    int m1;

    if (a < b || a < c) {
        m1 = a;
        return m1;
    } else 
    if (b < a || b < c) {
        m1 = b;
        return m1;
    } else
    if (c < a || c < b) {
        m1 = c;
        return m1;
    }

    // return m1;
}
```

Comment: неверная логическая операция используется

Comment: почему закомментирован последний return?

Comment: @Grundy, потому что он там не нужен. По задумке автора этот код недостижим. Просто при таком коде компилятор об этом не знает. Ну и ещё в коде баг, из-за которого он достижим.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите `return` из всех операторов `if` и раскомментируйте его в конце, также, чтобы получить всё таки МИНИМАЛЬНОЕ число из трёх возможных - нужно использовать логический оператор И (`&&`) а не ИЛИ (`||`)

Comment: Variable m1 might not have been initialized
        return m1;
               ^

Comment: @Andrew, ну так инициализируй его чем нибудь при объявлении

Comment: Я ставил public static и тоже ошибка

Comment: @Andrew при чем тут `public static`? Сделайте просто `int m1 = 0;`

Comment: Да, сделал, спасибо, но все равно сравнение неправильно сработало

Comment: System.out.println(min(1, 2, 3));
        System.out.println(min(-1, -2, -3));
        System.out.println(min(3, 5, 3));
        System.out.println(min(10, 5, 10));

Comment: Вывело
1
-3
0
5

Comment: В 3-м выводе должно было быть 3. Или у меня где-то неправильно условие записано?

Comment: аа, я понял почему, спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: @Andrew если какой-то ответ вас устроил, не забудьте отметить его как подходящий (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: Спасибо, я поставил, я просто не знал

Comment: @Grundy и AlMr, мож не надо костыли расставлять?

Comment: @Qwertiy, где костыль-то? :)

Comment: @Andrew, передай 3 равных значения и получи значение из "ну так инициализируй его чем нибудь при объявлении".

Comment: @Grundy, костыль в том, что не надо проверять взаимоисключающие ветви отдельно, когда можно использовать else. Инициализация мусором переменных, для которых алгоритм не предполагает инициализацию - это костыль. Ну и убирание return'ов - тоже костыль. По-хорошему, там вообще throw надо в конце ставить, если уж такой алгоритм кривой. Но лучше всё же поправить сами сравнения.

Answer (score 5):

Просто найти минимальное число из трёх можно так:

```
public static int min(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return (a < b && a < c) ? a : b < c ? b : c;
}
```

Если `a` меньше `b` и `c`, то возвращаем `a`. В противном случае если `b` меньше `c`, то возвращаем `b`, иначе - `c`.

---

И вариант с использованием `Math.min`:

```
public static int min(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return Math.min(Math.min(a, b), c);
}
```

Comment: @DeKaNszn тут весьма простые условия и короткие названия переменных.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @DeKaNszn, да без проблем прочитаю.

Answer (score 2):

1. Когда пишешь `return` в `if`, `else` уже писать не надо.
2. Когда все варианты закончились, `if` писать не надо.
3. У тебя баг и должно быть `&&`, а не `||`.
4. Ещё один баг - с равными числами проблема.
5. Лишнюю переменную можно не заводить при такой реализации.

```
public static int Min(int a, int b, int c) {
  if (a <= b && a <= c) {
    return a;
  }

  if (b <= a && b <= c) {
    return b;
  }

  return c;
}
```

Замечу, что последний if можно поменять:

```
public static int Min(int a, int b, int c) {
  if (a <= b && a <= c) {
    return a;
  }

  if (b <= c) {
    return b;
  }

  return c;
}
```

А ещё всё это можно записать условным оператором:

```
public static int Min(int a, int b, int c) {
  return a <= b && a <= c ? a : (b <= c ? b : c);
}
```